# Возвращение значения двух селектов в node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, select

Доброго времени суток.Работаю с node js. У меня есть функция которая возвращает значения выбраные с базы даных. Код на сервере

```
 function selectingManufacturer(callback) {
         var manufacturerdbArr = [];
         pool.pool.query('select name from manufacturer', function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err,null);
            }else {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    manufacturerdbArr.push(results[i].name);
                }
                callback(err,manufacturerdbArr);
            }
            });
         }
selectingManufacturer(function(err,manufacturerdbArr){
         if(err){
             console.log("ERROR : ",err);
         }else{
             ....
     });
```

Но мне нужно помимо даных с одной таблицы, выбрать их и с другой. Вохможно ли так сделать, и что б данные с обоих таблиц были доступны в одной функции. Примерно понимаю как, это должно работать но на практике не получаеться

Comment: Ну выполните оба запроса асинхронно, дождитесь ответа от каждого из запросов и оперируйте результатами 2ух и более запросов. Ну или можно сделать так - запрос 1ого запроса => на success 1сделать вызов 2ого запроса => success 2 запроса. Итог : на success 2 ого запроса  у вас есть результат 1 и результат 2. Промисы ваше основное "оружие"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В лоб это будет выглядеть так -

```
запрос_в_первую_таблицу(function(err,данные_1){
  запрос_во_вторую_таблицу(function(err,данные_2){
     //Теперь у вас есть и данные_1 и данные_2
     ваша_функция(данные_1,данные_2);
  });
});
```